# Set variable in Bash script to contents of file plus some text after

Tags: bash

How do I set a Bash variable in a shell script in redhat Linux to the contents of a file, which is only one line, and then add some text after it.

For example:

```
echo "Version 1.2.3.4" > $TMPDIR/devver
env=dev
export ${env}_result="`cat $TMPDIR/${env}ver` (No response - version is from cache)"
echo $dev_result
```

I want the output to be:

```
Version 1.2.3.4  (No response - version is from cache)
```

Instead, I get a newline after the version, like this:

```
Version 1.2.3.4
(No response - version is from cache)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem isn't in the variable setting it is in the file creation.  echo appends a newline to the file contents.  So use

```
echo -n "Version..."
```

and things should work.

Comment: Use `printf "Version..."` rather than `echo -n "Version..."` for better portability. It doesn't matter in this case, but it's a good habit.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bash builtin:

```
export ${env}_result="$(< $TMPDIR/${env}ver) (No response - version is from cache)"
echo "$dev_result"
```

Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):
"The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`."

Answer (score 1):

the utility `tr` may help:

```
echo "Version 1.2.3.4" | tr '\n' ' '> $TMPDIR/devver
env=dev
export ${env}_result="`cat $TMPDIR/${env}ver` (No response - version is from cache)"
echo $dev_result
```

tested :) it works.